# Node, Express and vue-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am trying to build an app the use node as a back-end and ejs as template engine and Vue as a fronted framework so the express is the router to the page and in the index.ejs page. I am including the script tage to the js page where it load the following command in the main.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

So this need to render the vue componnent into the the div tag that have an id of app the App.vue loks like that

```
<template>
   <h2>this is a template {{ title }}</h2>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title : 'shaked Vue',
      name : "shaked",
      ninjasx : [
        {
          name : "sjdhajs",
          showMe : false,
          mess : "we all have secreate"
        } ,
        {
          name : "shakex",
          showMe : false,
          mess : "we all black"
        } ,
        {
          name : "chxn",
          showMe : false,
          mess : "we all mr chen"
        }
      ]
    }
  } ,
  methods:{
    greet(){
      return 'hello world'
    } ,
    updateT(title){
      this.title = title.split("").reverse().join("")
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1{
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

and the express app look like that

```
      app.get('/' , function (req , res) {
    res.render('index', {data : "this is working"});
  });
```

and the ejs file like like that

```
<div id='app'></div>
<h1> <%= data %> </h1>
```

and no matter what I try I cannot get this to work it's at start says there is syntax error in the  `import Vue from 'vue'`. I need help connecting the two parts. I did some work with Vue as frontend and Node as backend but I cannot combine them.

Comment: The vue format you are using is the single file component format. That needs to be processed by something like the Vue loader and Webpack before a browser can use it. You need to 'build' it, then express would be able to serve the resulting files.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: It's all documented pretty well. You need to [build](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build) the project.